# Adding specific number of sections in a google form

Tags: forms

When an user enters a number into a field (representing the number of persons in a group), I want to have a section of google forms to be multiplied that many times - one for each person. In each such section I need to enter their details. Anybody did something similar to this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do isn't possible (without using App Scripts) but I have built a little [example](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScgYWVQguM7hvR885e7Tt1bBtu804T0Ios-RSawPMt-IqgCMw/viewform?usp=sf_link) of something that might work for you. Please see if this will work and get back to ASAP.

Pretty much it has a title page asks the user how many people they want to sign up. Then, depending on the answer, the form directs them to a section with the appropriate number of sign-ups.